# In a UICollectionView, the cells will not sit on the bottom

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Note** it turned out it was a simple mistake the cells would not "sit on the bottom". However, it's an interesting question: "how to move the cells up and down." Below a brute force solution: writing your own flow layout.

I was amazed that the only way to do it is entirely subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and write some tricky code in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`.

It's possible this will help someone in the future, as there is very little example code for `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` around.  Hope it helps.

--

It turns out **the reason my cells would not sit on the bottom** was that I previously had this in my UICollectionViewController...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// the following code is very useful to, for example,
// "nudge short lists towards the middle..." - if you want the list
// to more sit in the middle of the screen, when only a few items.
cvHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds);
[self.collectionView setContentInset:
       UIEdgeInsetsMake(cvHeight * 0.175, 0, cvHeight * 0.30, 0) ]; //top,l,b,r
}
```

of course, when I changed to a "full-view cell size" (one cell per screen), that code fails.

---

I have a simple UICollection view which is the width of an iPhone and about 250 high. The cells are the exact same size as the collection view.

The cells will not center, they always sit high. (i.e., outside the view.)

[image]

My collection view "sizes" in storyboard are all just zero. What could be the problem?

Comment: check on your Collection Cell, that might be the problem.

Comment: check the Autosizing on the Cell or add the Section Insets (Top) on the CollectionView

Comment: autosizing on the cell is unrelated.  setting section insets seems to achieve absolutely nothing - no change!

Comment: Make sure that you're not updating the collection view from outside the main thread or in a way that might cause it to update within an update, etc. I had some strange behavior that I traced back to that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi Caleb - thanks; absolutely no thread woes.  Thanks, though  :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one "brute force" way to solve the problem -- write your own FlowLayout!!

It works ...

```
class SimpleFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {


override init() {
    super.init()

    initialize()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

func initialize() {
    self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0

}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {

    return super.collectionViewContentSize
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {


    let allItems = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    for  attribute in allItems! {
        print ("attribute.frame.origin.y  .....  \(attribute.frame.origin.y)")
        attribute.frame = CGRect(x: attribute.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: attribute.frame.origin.y + 34,
                             width: attribute.frame.size.width,
                            height: attribute.frame.size.height)

            // "go figure" ... add 34
    }

    return allItems;

}
```

The way you "set" a UICollectionViewFlowLayout is basically like this...

```
class YourFancyDisplay: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = SimpleFlowLayout()
        ...
```

Comment: I just ticked this since it may help someone w/ example code for flow layout.  It's pretty much the only way to move them up and down!

Comment: @Fattie how exactly are you implementing SimpleLayout? Where are you using it as a subclass

Comment: I understand the implementation. However, I have one final question. In  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?  it looks like you are set the attributes for every cell in every index path. What if you cell two to have a different layout different than item one.

Comment: het Stef, just as in table view, you simply decide which custom cell to use.  see any tutorial for that - cheers, good luck

Comment: I looked at layoutAttributesForElements in the documentation and it states that it: Returns the layout attributes for all of the cells and views in the specified rectangle. Meaning custom cells would still conform to the layout.. Is there any other form/version of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. hopefully, it can help

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return collectionView.frame.size;
}
```

---

(For future readers, indeed you also typically need the other one ...)

```
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
     sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    return self.view.frame.size;
    }

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
   insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
    {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);   //t,l,b,r
    }
```

Comment: indeed .. unfortunately yes I am using that (or it won't work at all, heh!)   see .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915443  What a bummer.

Comment: Can u at NSLog above the return self.view.frame.size? just make sure the frame size is change to what it's supposed to be.

Comment: note that the SIZE is correct - it's the friction POSITION that is wrong!!!!!   how the hell do you set the POSITION ?!

Comment: I'm trying to help you. Did you check or uncheck the useAutoLayout?

Comment: Right, it's wild huh!  Damned apple!  :)   I AM NOT using auto layout.

Comment: Try this.
[colView setContentMode:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
[colView setContentSize: "sizeofthecollectionview"];
the best thing I can thing of

Comment: Nope!  didn't help!  notice the ridiculous "write your own flow layout" solution I posted -- it works!  :O